# Bash: If variable name is a specific pattern of chars do

Tags: bash, loops, variables

In bash i want to check if the name of a variable contains a specific pattern of chars like "abc" and if its true it should echo the variable. Preferably as an if loop.
So:

```
abc=1
```

or

```
opabc=1
```

should echo "1" 
but:

```
cba=1
```

should do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following, pure bash way. Please give script proper permissions and run it eg: `./script.ksh` or so. Also I have written `else` condition to print a statement like `string NOT found` etc, in case you do not want to print anything you could remove `else` part from this(though it is NOT good programming practice when we don't have proper statements, print statements on any check points are always helpful for any kind of troubleshooting IMHO).

```
cat script.ksh
var="abc=1"
val="${var%=*}"
val_field="${var#*=}"
if [[ "$val" =~ "abc" ]]
then
   echo "$val_field"
else
   echo "String abc NOT found."
fi
```

OR(as per @Benjamin W.'s comment adding his nice suggestion here as an alternative now)

```
cat script.ksh
var="abc=1"
IFS='=' read -r val val_field <<< "$var"
if [[ "$val" =~ "abc" ]]
then
   echo "$val_field"
else
   echo "String abc NOT found."
fi
```

Comment: @BenjaminW., thank you for letting know sir, added that alternative in solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are scanning some sort of configuration file.

```
awk -F= '$1~/abc/ {print $2}' input.cfg
```

Split the input at `=` signs. If field 1 contains `abc`, print field 2.

```
$ awk -F= '$1~/abc/ {print $2}' <<< 'abc=1'
1
$ awk -F= '$1~/abc/ {print $2}' <<< 'opabc=1'
1
$ awk -F= '$1~/abc/ {print $2}' <<< 'cba=1'
$
```